# How to open a Specific port on CentOS server

Tags: linux, centos, port

I want to open a port on my Cent Os remote server. I deployed a server application on the server which is using port 7500,when I tried making connection with it from my client client was not able to connect,then I changed the port to 8000 and client was able to connect to it,the port 8000 was allowed for access from outside,but all other ports are restricted,How can I open port 7500 on my server to access it.

when I checked  status firewalld using `systemctl status firewalld` it was not running and when I checked status of iptables using status iptables.service

```
iptables.service
Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
Active: inactive (dead)
```

Then by using what access to other ports except 8000 has been restricted
as firewalld is not running and iptables is inactive.Where can I check the ports which are allowed to be accessed from outside on server.

Answer (score 3):

You have Centos 7. It uses for default firewalld to manage firewall rules.
You can execute the command "systemctl status firewalld" in order to check if firewalld is running.

List the current firewalld configuration executing "firewall-cmd --list-all"

If firewalld is running use the following command to open 7500 tcp:

- Get the name of your zone

`firewall-cmd --get-active-zone`

- Open the port in the current configuration

`firewall-cmd --zone=YOURZONE --add-port=7500/tcp`

- Open the port in the current configuration valid after firewalld restart

`firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=YOURZONE --add-port=7500/tcp`

Answer (score 0):

You should check if SELinux is enabled or not. It could very well be blocking the port.

You should see what getenforce returns on the command line.  If it is running, the output would be "enforced"

You can temporarily place SELinux in "permissive" mode by running "setenforce 0".

If your service runs after doing so, then that means SELinux is blocking it.

You can see in the audit.log file to see why it is blocking your service.

Although one can say you disable SELinux, but I'd rather say figure why the service is blocked, use tools like audit2why to gather the details and then make changes to the SELinux policy to support the service. Turning off SELinux is not the right solution.

The reason why port 8000 worked for you is because port 8000 is by default allowed in SELinux policies, for port 7000 or 7500, you need to adjust the policy and explicitly mark them as allowed.

See what you find.

Comment: after doing  setenforce 0 it again didnt worked.Getenforce is returning permissive but it didnt worked. Except than Firewalld,iptables and Selinux what other thing might be blocking the port access.

Comment: Can you make the connection to that port while you are on the box locally? Use the telnet or curl utility to check.  curl http://localhost:7500. telnet 127.0.0.1 7500.

Comment: was able to connect using curl localhost:7500. Now how should I open this port for incoming connection from outside client.

Comment: Ok, so the next question is: is the client from where you are running this request a host and is the server running inside a VM, VMware or virtual box or something similar? Are you using NAT network settings or Bridge?  Here is the bare basics troubleshooting path, if SELinux and firewalld, both are turned off, there is nothing else on a stock centos7 image which will block the access, unless of course if iptables is installed, which I doubt.

Comment: My server is a remote Azure server based on CentOS. firewalld is not running. if I SetEnforce 0 then also unable to access the port.

Comment: By running this command "systemctl status firewalld" I am getting this output: firewalld.service - firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Comment: You are accessing this server on port 7500 from within another machine in the azure network (same subnet) or from the outside (essentially Internet)? If from the Internet, see if there are any firewall rules which azure requires you to add to their environment. This would be similar to opening ports on an edge firewall, and is also known as port forwarding.

Comment: I am accessing this port from an Internet connection outside of the Azure subnet.

Comment: Ok, so you need to setup something called port forwarding in order to reach that servers port 7500. I've not worked with an azure environment before so I do not know the specifics, but this is what you need, find out how to either do port forwarding for that server's port, or add a firewall rule in azure's environment to allow you to reach that server directly over the Internet. One of those will work and will allow you to move forward.